# jQuery droppable didn't executed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I just wrote a little drag-and-drop script with jQuery, but the drop part of the code won't work. I can drag the `#hoth` object and it returns to its original position when released, but nothing happens when I drop it on the `#yoda` object.

Here is the script:

```
$('#hoth').draggable({
    revert:true
});
$('#yoda').droppable({
    drop: function(){
        alert("asd");
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle with more code and html?

Comment: Your code works for me - http://jsfiddle.net/uufdV/ Did you include the required libraries? Are you running this code on DOM load?

Comment: It's also worked for me there. I pasted the complete CSS on jsFiddle.net, except the margins (because this is negative on the site) and the display:none attribute.

http://jsfiddle.net/uufdV/3/

Comment: Your example works too. Are you still having a problem?